# why is the tooltip working after i remove the link?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Only when I remove the link, I'm able to see the div tag with the tooltip. how does these two relate? the div content is not appearing with the link.

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}

div#tdemo1 {
  animation-name: animate;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
  }
  33% {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  66% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  99% {
    background-color: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body style="background-image:linear-gradient(180deg,blue,violet);">

  <div id="tdemo1" class="tooltip">Hover over me
    <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
  </div>
  <div id="bdemo1" class="container">
    <h1>types of buttons in bootstrap:</h1>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Primary</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Secondary</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">Success</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info">Info</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Warning</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Danger</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Dark</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light text-dark">Light</button>

  </div>
```

i tried to use the tooltip with a div tag and display buttons with bootstrap. Only one of these appears right at one time.

Comment: It seems *bootstrap* has a plugin that creates a `tooltip` class overriding your property settings. Move the `<link>` to the top of your `<header>`, before your own `<style>`. Check the BS: [Markup](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/tooltips/#markup) specs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the class of your `.tooltip` element, because `bootstrap` recognises it as a `bootstrap` element and rewrites its own values on it.

```css
.tooltipp {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltipp .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.tooltipp:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}

div#tdemo1 {
  animation-name: animate;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
  }
  33% {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  66% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  99% {
    background-color: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body style="background-image:linear-gradient(180deg,blue,violet);">

  <div id="tdemo1" class="tooltipp">Hover over me
    <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
  </div>
  <div id="bdemo1" class="container">
    <h1>types of buttons in bootstrap:</h1>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Primary</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Secondary</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">Success</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info">Info</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Warning</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Danger</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Dark</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light text-dark">Light</button>

  </div>
```